# Dask compute subgraph with futures

Tags: python-3.x, dask, concurrent.futures, dask-distributed

I want to submit a dask task that will do the following:

1. Build a lazy dask graph using dask.bag (`def fakejob`)
2. Compute the graph from 1. and save it to parquet (left this part out, just a motivation)

I need to do this for multiple inputs, so I've been trying to use the futures feature of dask.distributed like so.

```
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client(processes=True)

def fakejob(path):
    return (
        dask.bag
        .read_text(path)
        .to_dataframe()
    )

futures = client.map(fakejob, [input_path1, input_path2])
```

The problem is I keep getting: `AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children`

I've tried following [this link](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/task-launch.html) and ended up with a second version (differs in 1 line from the first), but the futures stay 'pending' forever.

```
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client(processes=True)

def fakejob(path):
    with dask.set_options(get=client.get):
        return (
            dask.bag
            .read_text(path)
            .to_dataframe()
        )

futures = client.map(fakejob, [input_path1, input_path2])
```

Any clues on how to do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strange and slightly humerous error message comes from trying to construct the dask graph (which is what a bag is) within a worker process, which is where things end up if called with client.map. Your second attempt would work with a local client if you could put the whole work-flow within the function, including writing to parquet, and didn't attempt to pass the bag back to the caller.

The solution is simpler.

```
bags = [dask.bag.read_text(path)
        .to_dataframe() for path in [input_path1, input_path2])
futures = client.compute(bags)   # run in background on the cluster
client.gather(futures)   # wait and get results
```

Here, `bags` is a list of dask-bags, i.e., work tasks defined but not yet running. You could replace the last two lines with `dask.compute(*bags)` to get the result without worrying about futures.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding :)

The solution you posted truly is simpler, but I think it doesn't address my problem. The list comprehension in `bags = ...` is going to build each graph in a sequential manner, correct? I actually wanted the building of the graph to also be in parallel. In other words, I want that list comprehension to happen in parallel.

Makes sense, or did I get something wrong?

Comment: Correct, the building of the list is in serial in the local thread - but is it slow for you? The only option, I think, would be to use `dask.delayed` and `db.from_delayed`, but this is what bag does internally on blocks of bytes; the only thing taking time is finding the size of each file.

Comment: I see. It takes a while actually. I'm experimenting with dask here at the office in the data science team. I'm using `dask.bag` to parse roughly 100GB/day of json data and converting it to parquet for a very specific analytics project. It's been working well, but it takes about 10 minutes to build the lazy object of the graph. we plan on evolving it further and this overhead could be an issue in the future. For now your suggestion is perfect. Thanks!